# How to insert jqueryUi (Show Effect -> Drop) in a php page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, effects

I'm trying to write from my database into my page, using one effect. The objective is, when it writes my comment on the page, show it with an effect.

```
<?php
    if(count($_POST) > 0){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo '$( "#toggle" ).toggle( "drop" );';
        echo '</script>';

        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "trab_projeto");

        $qr = $db->query("INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES ('{$_POST['mensagem']}')");

        echo "<fieldset id='toogle'>";
        echo "<p>";
        $row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row["comment"];
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</fieldset>";
    }
?>
```

The part of the script doesn't work.
These code is executed when I click on a submit form.

```
<div class="cadastro">
    <form action="" id="form-msg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <span><b>Escreva aqui o seu comentário:</b></span><br>
                <textarea name="mensagem" style="margin: 0px; width: 511px; height: 119px;"></textarea>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </fieldset>
    </form>     
</div>
```

Comment: You have a security issue regarding SQL Injection attacks. [Take a look at how to fix this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks! But that's not exactly what I want. I can insert on the database, but I'd like the comment appears with an effect.http://jqueryui.com/show/

Comment: Using the Drop option

Answer (score 0):

To return a JSON response, you must first place this in your `header()`. At the top of your script append:

```
header('Content-type: javascript/json');
```

Moving on, to prevent your SQL injection I have changed the driver to `PDO` which you can find documentation on.

```
header('Content-type: javascript/json');
$driver = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trab_projeto', 'root', 'password');
$state = false;
if(
    !isset($_POST['mensagem']) &&
    !empty($_POST['mensagem'])
) {
    $driver->Prepare('INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES (?)');
    $state = $driver->execute(array($_POST['mensagem']));
}
if($state)
{
    echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
    exit;
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
exit;
```

For future notice, this 'comment' it not attached to any 'thread' scope. If you have **multiple** posts, you should give each post a unique ID and cross-reference the post ID with the comment so you can load the comments for that specific post.

You can then use jQuery to send requests like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form-msg');
    comment = form.closest('textarea').val();
    $.post('the_file_path.php', { mensagem: comment })
        .done(function(response) {
            if(response.status) {
                // todo: success using the effect below
            }
        });
});
```

Note the following code above needs a `click()` attached to your submit button. Consider removing this line of code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

And using:

```
<button type='button'>Enviar</button>
```

So you can target it through the form like so:

```
form.closest('button').click(function() {
    // ...
}
```

You could use an effect when showing the comment to the user-end like so:

```
var commentToAdd = document.createElement('p');
commentToAdd.innerHTML = comment;
$('#comments').append(commentToAdd);
commentToAdd.show('slow');
```